# Are Dodd Frank rules applicable to all loan types?

Tags: bankruptcy

My student loan was transferred to a new servicer several months ago, and I never received notice, neither from the previous or the new servicer, of the assignment of my loan.  I thought that Dodd Frank required notification, but perhaps that only applies to mortgages?  I'm in Ch13 BK, and I only learned of the assignment after speaking with my previous servicer because my most recent payment was declines due to the account being closed.

I spoke with the new servicer over the phone, and they confirm that they have the account.  I requested that they send me written proof of the assignment, which they said they would do.  That was a week ago, and still nothing.  My guess is that they do not want me to make any payments during the Bk period, so that interest will accrue of the next 5 years.   #sofrustrating

Comment: The first hit in a search states without citing anything that both the old and new servicer must notify you: http://www.foxbusiness.com/personal-finance/2012/10/10/when-student-loans-are-sold-what-borrowers-should-know/

Comment: A holder must provide an means of repayment.  Pardon that I don't have a quick cite; just trying to help you.  Lean into them, and [as needed] threaten to get the repayment methods that you're due.